# How to use $gte and $lte between date with `$filter`

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a code  query `$gte` date, it works fine.

```
cityCollection.aggregate([
    { 
      "$project": { 
          theater: true,
          movie: {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$movie",
                  as: "movie",
                  in: {
                      cnName: "$$movie.cnName",
                      enName: "$$movie.enName",
                      releasedTime: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$$movie.releasedTime",
                          as: "movie",
                          cond: { $and:{
                            $gte: [ "$$movie", new Date(`${today} 20:00:00.000Z`) ]
                          }}
                        }
                      }
                  }
                }
              },
              as: "movie",
              cond: "$$movie"
            }
          }
      }
    }
])
    .then(drivers => res.send(drivers))
    .catch(next);
```

Now i want to query between two date, i try to add `$lte` inside my code like this:

```
releasedTime: {
   $filter: {
      input: "$$movie.releasedTime",
      as: "movie",
      cond: {
        $gte: [ "$$movie", new Date(`${today} 20:00:00.000Z`) ],
        $lte: [ "$$movie", new Date(`${today} 22:00:00.000Z`) ] 
      }
   }
}
```

But i get the error:

```
{
    "error": "An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: [ \"$$movie\", new Date(1526328000000) ], $lte: [ \"$$movie\", new Date(1526335200000) ] }"
}
```

I looking for some solution find `$and`,so i try to add `$and` in my code like this:

```
releasedTime: {
  $filter: {
    input: "$$movie.releasedTime",
    as: "movie",
    cond: { $and:{
      $gte: [ "$$movie", new Date(`${today} 20:00:00.000Z`) ],
      $lte: [ "$$movie", new Date(`${today} 22:00:00.000Z`) ] 
    }}
  }
}
```

It still shows the same error, i have no idea what step should i try.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's brackets `[]` and not braces `{}`, mostly because it's an "array of conditions" in the context of aggregation usage.

```
releasedTime: {
  $filter: {
    input: "$$movie.releasedTime",
    as: "movie",
    cond: { $and:[
      { $gte: [ "$$movie", new Date(`${today} 20:00:00.000Z`) ] },
      { $lt: [ "$$movie", new Date(`${today} 22:00:00.000Z`) ] }
    ]}
  }
}
```

There are actually examples at [`$and` (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) within the documentation. Such as [right here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/#example)

Also note you typically mean `$lt` when you want "up to" a specific range amount. Always go "less than" the "next highest value", rather than inclusive of the "largest possible".

Comment: Thanks @Neil . It helps me a lot. But i still don't understand you suggest use `$lt` not `$lte`. Why i should avoud use like `<=` 10:00. Any suggestion or link would be appreciated. Thank you very mych.

Comment: @徐博俊 The very simple reason why you do not is because if I want to "catch a movie" **between** 8pm and 10pm, then "equal to" is NOT "between". More evident by `$gte: new Date('2018-05-15'), '$lt': new Date('2018-05-16')` which means the "whole day" but if that was `$lte` then it actually covers no time at all, and using `$lte` to the 23rd hour, last minute, millisecond is just bad practice.